# Is anyone using BigQuery in combination with Google Colab?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-colaboratory

Thinking about how to set up a flexible query library I wonder whether Google Colab might be a good way to organize, document, and run queries on BigQuery. I have never used notebooks before but the fact that they allow for a structured approach could be really beneficial. I assume (but would like to have verified all the same) that I can simply define all kinds of subqueries, CTE's, functions, etc, in different sections of the notebook and then lastly define the actual master query taking all of those in?

Not sure if I could reuse certain notebooks that specifically hold more often used CTE's and functions either. That would surely be a bonus and a nice way to create the fundaments of such a library.

Any insights would be highly appreciated!

drftr

Answer (score 2):

You can use Google Cloud Client Library to interact with BQ  in a pythonic way wthin Google colab. [please check Link.](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/bigquery.ipynb)

Comment: Thanks for the link but it doesn't seem clickable. Would you mind retrying?

Comment: I've added the correct one.